# Preserve messages order when reading from IBM MQ with Kafka Connect

Tags: apache-kafka, ibm-mq, apache-kafka-connect

Is it possible to preserve message order (assign messages with the same key to the same partition) when reading from IMB MQ with Kafka Connect IBM MQ Source Connector using level of parallelism of 5 Tasks?

Answer (score 0):

By default, messages replicated using the source connector will have `null` key. You can use [Kafka SMTs](http://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html#connect_transforms) in order to create a key for your messages. In your connector's configuration, the following lines should do the trick (make sure to replace `messageId` with the field that you'd like to use as a key):

```
transforms=createKey
transforms.createKey.type=org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.ValueToKey
transforms.createKey.fields=messageId
```

Comment: I fear adding keys won't help here, because ordering can be broken between different tasks before even writing a message into kafka